# Unable to use SSL Proxy in Charles 4.0.2 on a remote device with iOS 10.3 beta 2 version. Any workaround available?

Tags: ios, ssl, charles-proxy

I am using Charles 4.0.2(licensed version) to sniff packets from a remote device with iOS 10.3 beta 2 version.

iOS versions prior to 10.3 works perfectly fine with my test setup; but 10.3 beta releases don't. I end up getting signing errors probably due to some security mechanism enforced in iOS versions. Any alternatives/workaround to this?

Comment: Can this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207459 be reason of issue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should go to the Device Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings -> Turn on Charles Proxy Custom Root Certificate